# Modify an new array then crash

Tags: swift, thread-safety

```
var list: [Int] = []
public func printListValues() {
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        while true {
            if self.list.count < 10 {
                self.list.append(self.list.count)
            } else {
                self.list.removeAll()
            }
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        while true {
            let newList = self.list
             newList.forEach { debugPrint($0) }

        }
    }

}
```

I know array is not thread-safe sometimes. But I have made `let value = self.list`. And it also crash with the information:

> Thread 3: Fatal error: Index out of range

on the line `newList.forEach { debugPrint($0) }`.

Why is `newList` not safe. What's the problem?

Comment: I made a swift playground with your source code pasted in and it ran just fine.

Comment: @IanMacDonald Swift Playgrounds are very bad for exploring threading issues. The way that they display information in the side-bar tends to force them into a sequential behavior even when the underlying operations are concurrent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array operations are not atomic. When you access the array in your second thread you have to be sure that it isn't in the middle of either the append() or removeAll() operation on the first thread otherwise you could be copying an array that is in an indeterminate state. Similarly one of these two operations could have occurred during the middle of the array copy operation which causes issues where the array changes state while it is being copied. You can fix your code by adding some thread synchronization.

```
var list: [Int] = []
var mutex = pthread_mutex_t()
public func printListValues() {
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, nil)
    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        while true {
            if self.list.count < 10 {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&self.mutex)
                self.list.append(self.list.count)
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&self.mutex)
            } else {
                pthread_mutex_lock(&self.mutex)
                self.list.removeAll()
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&self.mutex)
            }
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        while true {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&self.mutex)
            let newList = self.list
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&self.mutex)
            newList.forEach { debugPrint($0) }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

@Spads has great information about the problem (though I'd use GCD rather than pthreads to solve it), but it raises the question of how you would discover this if you didn't see the problem right away. The answer is the Thread Sanitizer, which will point you directly to where your problem is. It's a setting on the scheme (or you can pass `-sanitizer=thread` to `swiftc` directly).

[image: Thread Sanitizer setting in Xcode]

With that set, you will get the following in Xcode, pointing you directly to the lines that conflict.

[image]